# Bootstrap Как отключить float

Tags: bootstrap

Есть 2 div-а:

```html
<div class="container-fluid wraper">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="first" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></div>
    <div id="second" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Соответсвенно на маленьких разрешениях они становятся на весь экран и second подныривает под первый. Как сделать так, чтобы второй не подныривал, а оставался на месте. Т.е. его положение оставалось справа от первого, а сам  он был за overflow-y?

Comment: заменить `col-*-12` на `col-*-6` не пробовали?

Comment: зы: если не хотите использовать адаптивную верстку, то просто не используйте ее

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы именно на весь экран каждый див был на маленьком устройстве. А на большом устройстве пополам. Это не задача адаптивной верстки?

Comment: так у вас же указанно col-xs-12 что означает что они будут на 100% каждый, вам же это и надо? в чем проблема-то? или вам надо чтоб блоки были на 100% но внутренняя инфа была справа?

Comment: да. Код ниже вроде решил мою проблему. 2 дива на 100% а вместе на 200% в ряд. Это когда маленькое разрешение. А когда большое эти дивы по 50%. То есть задача была как с книгой, если в ландшафтном режиме - показывать 2 страницы, если в портретном - одну, а вторая сбоку, чтоб свайпом на нее переходить.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#left {
    height: 100vh;
    max-width: 50vw;

}

#right {
    height: 100vh;
    max-width: 50vw;
}
.up {
  max-width: 100vw;
}

@media (max-width: 970px) {
  #right, #left {
    min-width: 100vw;
  }
  .up {
    min-width: 200vw;
    max-width:200vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="up">
    <div class="cont container-fluid wraper">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="left" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 ">
                efsef
            </div>
            <div id="right" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                awdawd
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Вот так грубовато у меня таки получилось